# how to catch calls with LD_PRELOAD when unknown programs may be calling execve without passing environment

Tags: c, linux, dll

I know how to intercept system calls with `LD_PRELOAD`, that occur in compiled programs I may not have source for.  For example, if I want to know about the calls to `int fsync(int)` of some unknown program `foobar`, I compile a wrapper

```
int fsync(int)
```

for

```
(int (*) (int))dlsym(RTLD_NEXT,"fsync");
```

into a shared library and then I can set the environment variable `LD_PRELOAD` to that and run `foobar`.  Assuming that `foobar` is dynamically linked, which most programs are, I will know about the calls to `fsync`.

But now suppose there is another unknown program `foobar1` and in the source of that program was a statement like this:

```
execve("foobar", NULL, NULL)
```

that is, the environment was not passed.  Now the whole LD_PRELOAD scheme breaks down?

I checked by compiling the statemet above into `foobar1`, when that is run, the calls from `foobar` are not reported.

While one can safely assume most modern programs are dynamically linked, one cannot at all assume how they may or may not be using `execve`?

So then, the whole LD_PRELOAD scheme, which everybody says is such a great thing, is not really working unless you have the source to the programs concerned, in which case you can check the calls to `execve` and edit them if necessary.  But in that case, there is no need for LD_PRELOAD, if you have sources to everything.  LD_PRELOAD is specifically, supposed to be, useful when you don't have sources to the programs you are inspecting.

Where am I wrong here - how can people say, that LD_PRELOAD is useful for inspecting what unknown programs are doing??

Answer (score 0):

I guess I could also write a wrapper for `execve`.  In the wrapper, I add to the original `envp` argument, one more string: `"LD_PRELOAD=`my library`"`  .  This "seems" to work, I checked on simple examples.

I am not sure if I should be posting an "answer" which may very easily exceed my level of C experience.

Can somebody more experienced than me comment if this is really going to work in the long run?